# SSRS Switch Colour Expression multiple groups criteria

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I trying to colour code a group within a group based on a value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXih8.png)

I am quite new to SSRS, and have tried various expressions, SWITCH, IIF etc but I cant seem to get them to reference the various criteria and groups correctly.

Comment: What is your criteria?  What expressions are being used at the moment? There's not enough for anyone to help you with at the moment. Also, please edit your tags to reference the version of SSRS you are using.

Comment: sorry Alan, I have edit the tags, and added another picture in with the current expressions.

Comment: Please read this for future reference. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If you follow these guidelines you will get better help, faster. People are very helpful on SO but they also use their own time to help others and will often skip over a question if there's not enough info attached, or they will vote to close it for the same reason. I will attempt to answer but please bear this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You've not explained what your criteria is so this is just a guess. I'm also assuming that the `Target` values are numeric, so `5` and not `5 days` for example.

I'm also assuming that you want the background to be green is the count of `DAYS2` >= `Target`

If this is the case then you can do something simple like this

```
=IIF(COUNT(Fields!DAYS2.Value) < Fields!Target.Value, "Green", "Red")
```